# How does the VIP supply officer work?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

As of a recent update, they seem to have revised the Imperial levels. Before, each level built one widget, but now they can built multiple types of widgets. If you delivered a Supply Officer to a level, they would begin construction of the widget. But now, you have to pay to start construction of an item - what if you deliver a Supply Officer to a level which has not started construction? Do you still have to pay to start it? I can't tell since I haven't received a Supply Officer for a while now.

Sidenote: It seems like this new update has made everything more expensive. The returns on the missions are ridiculous - one mission requires 66 components and pays out less than 75K gold - starting the construction for them is going to cost me more gold than that already!

Comment: Agreed.  This update is lack-luster.  I'm thinking of deleting.

Comment: I'm starting to feel the same way. It actually feels like a step backwards - I would have thought you would get at least 1 more residential level at least to cover the Panama City Pharma level from the Christmas event.

Answer (score 2):

**SUPPLY OFFICER:**
Delivering this character to the corresponding imperial level, will allow it to work on the item being built with no cost and finishes it immediately.

It is like a worker so it can not start the item being built, it only finishes the item. So you will still have to pay.

Supply Officers can not be delivered above Imperial Levels. If the user were to try to do so, a dialog box would say "Supply Officers can only be delivered to Imperial Levels". If it is delivered to an Imperial Level with no tasks, it will just leave.

Answer (score 0):

It completes the item being built immediately. It's like a mega-worker.

Comment: But do you still have to pay to get it started? You didn't have to spend gold to do it before the update.

Comment: yes, you still have to pay to get it started.  If you deliver a Supply Officer to an Imperial floor with no projects started, the VIP will just walk away, not prompting you to start new construction.

Comment: @rbf2000 That answers the question. If you post it as the answer, I'll mark it as such.